# how to upload video on youtbe using youtuba data api insert method?

Tags: youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to create a youtube upload script that does not require the end user to login in order to upload a video to my channel. The issue is I can gain the access token but it expires after an hour of being inactive. Also I am unsure where you can get the "refresh token" from.

can we avoid consent screen when we upload video on youtube ? when i click on upload button that time open screen of choose account and after select account i got response on another tab, but i want response on same page. i am using node js and using insert meyhod for uploading videos on youtube channel.

So essentially I wish to have this Google API v3 script not require any client side authentication in order to upload video's.

From what I gather from the API documentation at google if I had the "refresh_token" I could renew the token without the need of user interaction required.

Comment: https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Cloud-Hub/Access-token-expiration-time/m-p/529779#M1961